# Bootstrap border of td element problem with colspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I put a solid red border in the first td but I see that border olso on border-top of others td.

HTML -> a simple table with a head row with colspan 2 and a row in body with 2 columns:

```
<table class="table ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="pen-cell" colspan="2">HEAD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="pen-cell current" id="pen-cell-1">1</td>
      <td class="pen-cell" id="pen-cell-2">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS -> color for head and body, red border for "current" cell:

```
table td.pen-cell {
  background-color: #ead6a4;
  border: 1px solid #e09c37;
}
.table thead th.pen-cell {
  background-color: #e09c37;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e09c37 25%, #fff 85%);
  border: 1px solid #e09c37;
}
td.current {
  padding: 0rem;
  border: 6px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

the problem is that the red border is present also on border-top of the second cell.

live version: https://codepen.io/Migio/pen/ExPoJwj

Comment: Just a note: I opened that codepen in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari (all on MacOS). Firefox behaves correctly (i.e. it does *not* apply the red top border to the second `td`), but all others act as you describe. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

Really good question. I've tested it it different ways and looks like it is some bug of `table`. This happens only when previous element has `colspan="2"` combined with `table {border-collapse: collapse;}` which is added by Bootstrap actually.

Here is more stable solution using `display: grid;`

More about [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) and [grid-area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.table>div {
  background-color: #ead6a4;
  border: 1px solid #e09c37;
}

.table #head-cell {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; /* like a colspan, but better */
  background-color: #e09c37;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e09c37 25%, #fff 85%);
  border: 1px solid #e09c37;
}

.table>div.current {
  padding: 0rem;
  border: 6px solid #ff0000 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div id="head-cell">HEAD</div>
  <div id="pen-cell-1" class="current">1</div>
  <div id="pen-cell-2">2</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

Using Bootstrap cols

```css
.table>div {
  background-color: #ead6a4;
  border: 1px solid #e09c37;
}

.table #head-cell {
  background-color: #e09c37;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e09c37 25%, #fff 85%);
  border: 1px solid #e09c37;
}

.table>div.current {
  border: 6px solid #ff0000 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row table">
    <div class="col-12" id="head-cell">HEAD</div>
    <div class="col-6 current" id="pen-cell-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-6" id="pen-cell-2">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, do you think that this method is better than bootstrap grid system? (col-12, col-6...)

Comment: Oh, I thought you have used table and not BS `col` for some reason. It's totally fine to use BS grid system based on `flex`. Updated the answer with one more solution. Look please.